# Node.js brute force prevention

Tags: node.js, security, brute-force, server-side-attacks

I have a MERN stack project running on Heroku, today someone has started to flood my server with many login requests (brute force). Every request has a different IP address so I cannot block the IP. This has caused a website outage.

How can I block it then? How can I allow login only using my website?

Comment: Are you sure that every single request comes from a different IP address?  That seems unlikely.  The attacker may be using multiple IP addresses, but it would be unusual if you never saw a repeat request from the same IP address.

Comment: yes, checking the logs every request's fwd="ip" has a different one..

Comment: One typical solution is to require human interaction upon login such as a captcha or the no-captcha solution that asks the user to click a specific spot on the screen with the mouse (and uses a detector to see if this looks like a real user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical solution you will see used by many login pages is one of several techniques that require human-like interaction and are hard for scripts to duplicate.

You have, for sure, seen the [captcha systems](http://www.captcha.net/) that ask the user to interpret some image that is not easy or practical for computers to analyze.

There is also a [no-captcha system](https://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/captcha-alternatives-better-ux) that asks the user to click a particular spot on the screen with the mouse and it analyzes the movement to see if it appears human-like.  These are often shown as a click on "I'm not a robot".

Many sites (like some U.S. airlines and a number of financial sites) now require the user to set up "challenge" questions (like: "Where were you born?" or "What's your favorite ice cream flavor?") and if a login request arrives without a previous placed signed cookie for this user (or other familiar browser detection metrics), then the challenge question is required before you can even attempt a login.

A more draconian approach (that could have more of an impact on the end-user) is to keep track of failed login attempts per account and after a certain number, you start slowing down the responses (this slows down the attackers systems) and after some higher number of failed responses, you immediately fail every request and require the end-user to confirm their login request via an email message sent to their registered email address.  This is an inconvenience for the end-user, but prevents more than N guesses on any individual account without end-user confirmation.  After some period of time, you can clear the prior login attempt numbers for any given account, freeing it up to work normally again.

Comment: I added recaptcha V2 on front-end and back-end :) now he's receiving status 400 bad request because he doesn't have captcha!! thank you :)