# How can I safely implement my login routes?

Tags: javascript, express, web, middleware

I am currently making a login and registration system as a project for a website, but I am uncertain of how I can safely implement the routes/logic for it. Currently, in my client side code I send a fetch request to my login or register route, and do the logic there, and then send a JSON object back, which is manipulated whether there is an error or not, and I have implemented CORS and Header (Origin and Referrer headers) authorization middleware within my POST routes, so no external script can mass produce users/login [aka brute force]. Is there another safer and better way of handling this?

Comment: what do you mean by `I send a fetch request to my login or register route`? How can you do that from server-side code?

Comment: I mean that I send a POST request using fetch() to my login or register routes (which is /login for login and /register for the registration route).  Sorry, I meant client side code @Prajapati

Comment: FYI, using CORS head origin or referrer headers does not stop anyone from mass producing login attempts.

Comment: Do you know a way I can stop that?

Comment: The only good options I know of are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743119/node-js-brute-force-prevention/64743312#64743312).

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of that. I just thought like if a user used an external script and requested the routes, it would do so, but captcha seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is, to use either `JWT` or `Session Cookies`.
Algorithm ->

1. User visits the /login page
2. User enters user id and password
3. U send a fetch or Axios request to your servers `POST API` route

```js
axios(`/<api_route_here>`,{
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`
     }
})
```

In the above code, we are encoding the username and password with base64 and then sending them back to the server with the Authorization header. `username:password`

Note: Make sure u are using an HTTPS connection

4. In the server u decode the Authorisation value from the header. Then create a hash of the password with username as its salt. Then query your database if the hash matches the user's password's hash.

We are hashing here to prevent leaking passwords in case of a database hack.
It is obvious, that you will store the password for the user using the same hashing technique.

5. If the query is positive then send a 200 response else send a 401.
6. In the Axios promise resolution check for the headers status code to figure out if the sign-in was successful

To prevent asking the user their password every time. U must use session cookies. i.e in step 4 if the password is correct add a `Set-Cookie` header property with a session token value. Store that session token to your database. Next time you API is hit, check for the cookie. if the cookie exists then check that session token with your database. otherwise, send a `401`

To prevent route spamming, implement a captcha.

Comment: Thank you. I was doing this except the encryption part, and I'll consider also using this alongside captcha.

Comment: Did do that sir